# Local variables not being passed to functions defined within a separately loaded class - python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a main python file:

`mainFile.py`:

```
a = 1
b = 2

from MyClass import MyClass # import class here as variables used by MyClass will be defined above.
test = MyClass()
test.afunction()
```

And the class defined as:

`MyClass.py`:

```
class MyClass():
    def afunction(self):
        return a + b
```

I would like this to return `1+2=3` when I run `mainFile.py`. However, I get the following error:

```
    return a + b
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I can do this simply in a single file:

```
a = 1
b = 2

class MyClass():
    def afunction(self):
        return a + b

test = MyClass()
test.afunction()
```

And running this returns `3`. However, given the length of my class definition, I want it in a separate file.

I have tried declaring `global a`, but it still doesn't 'see' `a` or `b`. It is not practical to define `a` and `b` as inputs into `afunction(self, a, b):`. ( `afunction` gets called by another function within a package, and I don't want to edit the call to `afunction` inside the official functions of this other package).

Happy to give more information if needed. I'm also happy to provide actual examples rather than this somewhat abstracted MWE: I'm using the `FPDF` module to make PDF reports with python. The class defines the `header` and `footer` in which an image, title and author are added. The `logo_path`, `title` and `author` are all set in the main python script. If I move the class definition into a separate file, then it obviously doesn't see the variables `logo_path`, `title` and `author`.

Comment: Are you able to modify MyClass? if so, did you try to add a and b to `__init__` of MyClass?

Comment: "Globals" in Python are *per module*. If you want it to be automatically available everywhere, you have to put it in `builtins`. That's a bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you're trying to do (without absurd amounts of reflection). You do have few options, though:

## Put the variables in `MyClass`'s constructor (recommended)

**MyClass.py**

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def afunction(self):
        return a + b
```

**mainFile.py**

```py
from MyClass import MyClass

a = 1
b = 2

test = MyClass(a, b)
test.afunction()
```

## Set the variables in MyClass.py from within mainFile.py

**MyClass.py**

```py
a = 1
b = 2

class MyClass:
    def afunction(self):
        return a + b
```

**mainFile.py**

```py
import MyClass

MyClass.a = 1
MyClass.b = 2

test = MyClass()
test.afunction()
```

## If you really do want to access the variables of mainFile.py from within MyClass.py

This is here in case someone knows that this is what they want to do and finds this question. While valid use-cases for doing this do exist, they are few and far between. (this is the aforementioned "absurd amounts of reflection")

**MyClass.py**

```py
from contextlib import suppress
import sys


_this_mod = sys.modules[__name__]


class MyClass:
    def afunction():
        for mod in sys.modules.values():
            for attr in dir(mod):
                if ((getattr(mod, attr) is _this_mod and mod is not _this_mod)
                        or getattr(mod, attr) is afunction):
                    with suppress(AttributeError):
                        return getattr(mod, 'a') + getattr(mod, 'b')
```

**mainFile.py**

```py
import MyClass

a = 1
b = 2

test = MyClass.MyClass()
test.afunction()


# or


from MyClass import MyClass

a = 1
b = 2

test = MyClass()
test.afunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as below. Simply pass the variables to your constructor and make sure your constructor is prepared to process them. As a bonus you could add a setter so you can set the parameters in one line/call.

**myscript.py**

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def params(self):
        return self.a, self.b
        
    @params.setter
    def params(self, data):
        self.a, self.b = data

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

        #transpose kwargs to self
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            self.__dict__[key] = kwargs[key]

    def afunc(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

****main**.py** ... or whatever

```
from myscript import MyClass
a = 1
b = 2

test = MyClass(a=a,b=b)
c = test.afunc()
print(c) #3

#change a and b example
test.params = (60, 20)
c = test.afunc()
print(c) #80
```

**Alternately**, if you only have a couple of kwargs, this is cleaner.

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def params(self):
        return self.a, self.b
        
    @params.setter
    def params(self, data):
        self.a, self.b = data

    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0): #note: keywords are used directly
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```